# Google Cloud SQL: unsupported XML feature

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

Do Postgres databases on Google Cloud SQL support an XML type field? I am trying to import a Postgres 9.5 dump which has XML type fields and it throws an error saying `unsupported XML feature`.

Full error message from Google Cloud SQL console:
`ERROR: unsupported XML feature DETAIL: This functionality requires the server to be built with libxml support. HINT: You need to rebuild PostgreSQL using --with-libxml.`

I couldn't find any way to rebuild PostgreSQL on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Supported flags for postgres Cloud SQL instances are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#list-flags-postgres). There is an open public [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63922754) for supporting this flag. I suggest you to add your use case there which would higher the possibility of implementation.